# Convert the str to list of tuple

Tags: python, dataframe

I call the oxidation states of A and B in AB compounds from list1 ('CaFe', 'BaSi', 'SeOs', 'BaGeO', 'CdCe'):

```
dfA = pd.read_csv("oxi_state.csv",index_col=0, header =0)
A1 = []
A2 = []
final = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
   A1 = dfA['OS'][list1[i][0]]
   A2 = dfA['OS'][list1[i][1]]
   A = (A1, A2)
   final.append(A)
final
```

When I have called the data from DataFrame. The data is in the form:

```
[('2', '2,3,4'),
 ('2', '4'),
 ('-2,4,6', '4,5,6,7'),
 ('2', '2,4'),
 ('2', '3,4')]
```

Now I want to convert in the following form:

```
[([2], [2, 3, 4]),  ([2], [4]),  ([-2,4,6], [4,5,6,7]),  ([2], [2,4]),  ([2], [3,4])]
```

For post processing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show an extract from the CSV

Comment: Atom OS
Ba         2
Ca         2
Cd         2
Ce         3,4
Ag       1,2,3
Am       3,4

Is it fine or do I need to share csv file. @Albert Winestein

Comment: That sample makes no sense in the context of your question. If that's the first line in your CSV file then dfA['OS'] will result in KeyError.

Comment: @NeeleshGupta please post an actual example of the CSV. You don't need loops to split column values in a Pandas dataframe. You could write `C=df['A'].str.split(',')` to generate a new series C with value lists per row, or `df['C']=df['A'].str.split(',')` to add the new series to the original dataframe.  Finally, you can use  [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to convert the dataframe into an array. That's three lines of fast code, far faster than looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear how the list of tuples is being created. However, based on the sample shown then:-

```
lot = [('2', '2,3,4'),
 ('2', '4'),
 ('-2,4,6', '4,5,6,7'),
 ('2', '2,4'),
 ('2', '3,4')]

for i, e in enumerate(lot):
    lot[i] = [list(map(int, e_.split(','))) for e_ in e]

print(lot)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[2], [2, 3, 4]], [[2], [4]], [[-2, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[2], [2, 4]], [[2], [3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have to loop through all of the items. Using

```
list('2,3,4')
```

will return

```
['2',',','3',',','4']
```

You can then go through and remove the commas and convert the str to int

Comment: Can you provide a code for that? I am bit new in python.

Answer (score 0):

Use split method with `,` as a seperator.

```
   A1 = list(int(x) for x in dfA['OS'][list1[i][0]].split(","))
   A2 = list(int(x) for x in dfA['OS'][list1[i][1]].split(","))
```

Comment: It is giving in this form (['2'], ['2', '3', '4']). But the desired one is like([2], [2, 3, 4]). Still not matching the requirement.. @gowtham758550

Answer (score 0):

Here a brute force solution :

```
a = [('2', '2,3,4'),
 ('2', '4'),
 ('-2,4,6', '4,5,6,7'),
 ('2', '2,4'),
 ('2', '3,4')]

fin = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  tup = []
  for j in a[i]:
    tmp = []
    for v in j.split(','):
      tmp.append(int(v))
    tup.append(tmp)
  fin.append(tuple(tup))
```